# Handling bad CSV records in CsvHelper

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I would like to be able to iterate through all records in a CSV file and add all the good records to one collection and handle all the "bad" ones separately. I don't seem to be able to do this and I think I must be missing something.

If I attempt to catch the BadDataException then subsequent reads will fail meaning I cannot carry on and read the rest of the file -

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        if (!reader.Read())
            break;

        var record = reader.GetRecord<Record>();
        goodList.Add(record);
    }
    catch (BadDataException ex)
    {
        // Exception is caught but I won't be able to read further rows in file
        // (all further reader.Read() result in same exception thrown)
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The other option discussed is setting the BadDataFound callback action to handle it -

```
reader.Configuration.BadDataFound = x =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Bad data: <{x.RawRecord}>");
};
```

However although the callback is called the bad record still ends up in my "good list"

Is there some way I can query the reader to see if the record is good before adding it to my list?

For this example my Record definition is -

```
class Record
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And the data (first row bad, second row good) -

```
"Jo"hn","Doe",43
"Jane","Doe",21
```

Interestingly handling a missing field with MissingFieldException seems to function exactly as I would like - the exception is thrown but subsequent rows are still read ok.

Comment: Well, the file format does not specify such a thing as a "bad row". What you encounter is a corrupted file and reading that further, guessing what the rest of it might after the format specification failed is kinda pointless. It's not valid CSV.

Comment: I dont understand your last comment, if  `MissingFieldException` is what you want and what does what you need, why it doesnt work?

Comment: Why don't you put the instruction  if (!reader.Read()) break; before try { } in the while block?

Comment: @nvoigt I agree the file format does not say what a bad row is and unfortunately I don't have control over the source, but if you set the BadDataFound callback action, CsvHelper is able to work out what the bad row is perfectly and continue to the next one.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry probably trying to fit too much in the question and not being clear. There are 2 potential errors from CsvHelper - BadDataException which is thrown for the data I show in the question and MissingFieldException for if "Doe", was missing for example. The handling of this second type or error works exactly as I would like - throws an exception but allows reading of further records in the file.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette the reader.Read() is what throws the exception so if I put it outside the try block I have no chance of being able to recover and read further rows.

Comment: @Zak In this case, the best is to read the CSV file line by line as a normal text file and parse each string. If there is no comma in the strings, you can use Split (', ')

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette That may be the route I have to go. However at least one field could contain almost any text at all, including a comma,  so I was hoping to use a library which had covered all scenarios and for the most part CsvHelper has been it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is the [example](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/803) I supplied.

```
void Main()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("FirstName,LastName");
        writer.WriteLine("\"Jon\"hn\"\",\"Doe\"");
        writer.WriteLine("\"Jane\",\"Doe\"");
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        var good = new List<Test>();
        var bad = new List<string>();
        var isRecordBad = false;
        csv.Configuration.BadDataFound = context =>
        {
            isRecordBad = true;
            bad.Add(context.RawRecord);
        };
        while (csv.Read())
        {
            var record = csv.GetRecord<Test>();
            if (!isRecordBad)
            {
                good.Add(record);
            }

            isRecordBad = false;
        }

        good.Dump();
        bad.Dump();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you need to put the row var record = csv.GetRecord<Test>(); inside the if block

Comment: This do not seems to work anymore in CsvHelp on 2021. The line csv.Configuration.BadDataFound  = context ...  throws Read Only Property. It Seems that once upon a time friendly CsvHelp library is now more convoluted and complex to handle. I'm starting to think that write my own parser will be less work that to try to understand how prevent that CSVHelp throws exceptions of BadData.. sigh

Comment: @FidelOrozco Configuration changed to read only to avoid threading issues. You just need to create a config and pass in into the constructor. The change is in the change log, and the docs were updated to reflect this. I can't be expected to update every stack overflow question, but I will when I come across them. If you want to write your own, awesome! Submit it to the speed test. https://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2020/12/fastest-net-csv-parsers He's adding compatibility tests in the future also.

Comment: @JoshClose - I've been scouring the GitHub and project site trying to find the examples you mention here, but I can't seem to find any way to "create a config and pass it into the constructor" as you've suggested.  My interpretation was to create an instance of CsvConfiguration, and set its BadDataFound delegate, but the only constructor on CsvConfiguration takes a CultureInfo and nothing else.  Trying to set the BadDataFound delegate on the instance itself just causes the same read-only issue the grumbling complainer mentioned above.

Comment: @JoshClose - Never mind.  My weariness led me to forget how object initializers work. ‍♂️ Coming across this comment made me wake up.  https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/803#issuecomment-766199301

Answer (score 0):

This can be done while loading the whole list at once. This is generic implementation. See comments inline

```cs
public static List<TOut>? CsvLoad<TMap, TOut>(string path) where TMap : ClassMap<TOut> where TOut : class, 
{
    List<TOut>? modelList = null;

    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        config.ReadingExceptionOccurred = re =>
        {
            // HERE YOU CAN DO ANYTHING YOU WANT WITH A BAD ROW
            Debug.WriteLine($"Bad Row in file '{path}'; CSV ERROR: {re.Exception}");
            return false; // <-- tells process to continue
        };      


        try
        {

            using (var stream = new StreamReader(path))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(stream, config))
            {
                csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<TMap>();
                modelList = csv.GetRecords<TOut>().ToList(); // <-- get all records
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // This must be some bad exception
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // LOG, THROW EXCEPTION, whatever
    }
    return modelList;

}
```

Note: more configurations can be added as needed. Can add `options` parameter to the method.